# Initializing cache for Primefaces autocomplete component on page load

Tags: caching, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm using primefaces (5) autocomplete component where the total number of options is around 500. While this is a high number, the data sent is quite simple and the transfer from server to client is quick.

I was wondering if it is possible to preload/cache all autocomplete options on page load in order to avoid any ajax delay while the user is writing text.

Does anyone know of how to do this?

Comment: I can't see the advantage of this, basically the whole purpose of the autocomplete is not to load all the values from the datasource. If it's not a problem for you loading those 500 options, why don't you consider using a selectOneMenu with filter="true" ?

Comment: The main purpose of the autocomplete component is to help the user complete input data, not to choose from a list. Also, I like primefaces' autocomplete because it easily supports multiple selection and because of its tag-like UI (boxing each item).

Comment: The cache in the autocomplete component is not that smart. basically the cache is based on query, for example if you wrote "c" [the results of this query are going to be cached](http://goo.gl/GCLTKv) by "c" as a key, so having all your options to support cache out of the box, meaning without any change to the original JS script is impossible. Thus you should reimplement the [search](http://goo.gl/9gISmH) function.

Comment: I agree, one of the solutions would be to use [Prime-UI's](http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/autocomplete.html) implementation on autocomplete. But then I would lose support to bean converters, which is my case. I guess I'll have to live with that initial request delay.